# Is there a way to shorting this regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am not very good at regular expressions so i have hacked a solution to ignore whitespaces or new lines

here is my string which i am trying to find a match

```
    $str = 'name="something"> function
    (para
    m)';
```

The string may have line breaks or whitespaces anywhere. Please note that i do not want a implementation to  which includes string replacing on \n or \r or " ", as my real string is a PDF file containing human readable text.

My current solution is to wrap each character in (MY CHAR HERE)(\s)* as you can imagine my regex will be rather large for a big search string ie

```
    (n)(\s)*(a)(\s)*(m)(\s)*(e)(\s)*(=)(\s)*(")(\s)*(s)(\s)*(o)(\s)*(m)(\s)*(e)(\s)*(t)(\s)*
```

etc..............

Is there a simplier/cleaner solution for this?

My end goal is to do preg_replace

so hopefully something like this

```
    $pattern = ''; //My new pattern here

    $str = 'name="something"> function
    (para
    m)';

    $replace = 'name="something"> different function(param1, param2){} function(param)';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse PHP code? If so, you might want to check out [NikiC's PHP parser on GitHub](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).

Comment: Sorry just updated my question to show my end goal

Comment: This `n\s*a\s*m\s*e\s*=\s*"\s*s\s*o\s*m\s*e\s*t\s*`

Comment: Unfortunately im trying to parse a pdf file which contains xml and js, i need to find a point in the file and replace it with a new js script

Comment: @KorushMahdavieh please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically construct a regex to add `\s*` inbetween each char.

*I've seen very large regex strings, so thats not a concern. It might be

a tad slower, but not too much I don't think.*

Split the string into chars, join it with '\s*' then use the regex.
Physically you could see it better (with one of those regex format programs)  -

`n\s*a\s*m\s*e\s*=\s*"\s*s\s*o\s*m\s*e\s*t\s*`

```
 n \s* 
 a \s* 
 m \s* 
 e \s* 
 = \s* 
 " \s* 
 s \s* 
 o \s* 
 m \s* 
 e \s* 
 t \s*
```

Comment: I was just hoping there was a more elegant solution

Comment: But as said, there is no other way to do it. Speed won't be a factor, and if already dynamically constructed, you never have to look at it. There is _no_ way else to do it, no elegant solution, none..

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better way to construct a pattern:

```
$pattern = preg_replace('@\s+@', "\s+", preg_quote($str));
```

Comment: This does replace all existing 1 or more whitespace with '\s+', but he says it like its arbitrary and wants to put `\s*` inbetween everything. So possibly a find like `~\s+|(.)~`, replace like `$1\s*`.

Comment: That was not my understanding. If he really wants to put \s* inbetween everything, I better delete my answer and vote for stripping whitespaces :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just strip all whitespace first, then run your match on the result of that. Much easier ;)

Comment: 'The string may have line breaks or whitespaces anywhere. Please note that i do not want a implementation to which includes string replacing on \n or \r or " "'. Why he refuses to do this simple and elegant solution no one knows (probably not even him).

Comment: I need this solution to be as quick as possible

Comment: Pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: And stripping spaces first is significantly more optimal than trying to match arbitrary spaces throughout your pattern.

Comment: "I am not very good at regular expressions so i have hacked a solution". These regex experts are giving you a solution, yet you think your solution is better.

Comment: Ok i understand that but there are other reasons for not striping whitespaces such as my real string is a PDF file containing human readable text. I have updated my question